# Не отрабатывает условие if в блоке catch java

Tags: java, исключения, рекурсия, if

есть проблема, есть метод который через gmail api получает письмо и сравнивает его с нужным текстом , если письма с нужным емайлом нет выкидываеться IndexOutOfBoundsException если текст в письме не совпадает с нужным текстом то AssertionError. Я сделал рекурсию и если выкидывается ошибка то счетчик увеличивается и происходит рекурсия, для выхода из этой рекурсии добавил условие что если счетчик больше 10 то выкидывается исключение, но почему то это условие не отрабатывает, хотя счетчик увеличивается, это видно в логах, там отображаются номера попыток и их почему то больше 10, рекурсия уходит в бесконечность.

Вопрос, почему условие  if (tryGetMail>10){log.info("Нужное письмо таки и не получено"); new NullPointerException();} не отрабатывает? Ниже приведен код.

```
int tryGetMail = 0;



public void checkOfferInMailClient(String verificationText, String mailTitle) {
        try {
            GmailApi gmailApi = new GmailApi();
            String actualText = gmailApi.getTextMail(mailTitle);
            String actualTextNoSpace = actualText.replaceAll(" ", "");
            String verificationTextNoSpace = verificationText.replaceAll(" ", "");
            Assert.assertTrue(verificationTextNoSpace.contains(actualTextNoSpace),
                    "Текст в письме не совпадает ожидаемому результату");
            log.info("Текст из письма проверен успешно");
        } 

catch (InterruptedException | GeneralSecurityException | IOException ex) {
            log.error("Все плохо и ничего не прочиталось:(");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Проблема с текстом письма");
        }
 catch (AssertionError|IndexOutOfBoundsException ae){
            tryGetMail++;
            log.info(tryGetMail+" попытка получить письмо.");
            if (tryGetMail>10){
                log.info("Нужное письмо таки и не получено");
                new NullPointerException();}
            checkOfferInMailClient(verificationText, mailTitle);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (tryGetMail > 10) {
            log.info("Нужное письмо так и не получено.");
            throw new NullPointerException(); // !!!
        }
```

или

```
        if (tryGetMail > 10) {
            log.info("Нужное письмо так и не получено.");
        } else { // !!!
            checkOfferInMailClient(verificationText, mailTitle);
        }
```

Comment: Ок,  попробую добавить else, но разве он  и без него не должен был заходить в if когда tryGetMail  становился 10 , и вываливаться по exeption?

Comment: @Иван У Вас нет `throw` перед `new NullPointerException()`. Так что Вы создаете объект исключения, но не бросаете его.